# pgfplots: modify scale of y-axis in stacked plots individually for each groupplot

Tags: plot, latex, tikz

I need to plot results out of various simulation with different parameter settings. They all share the same categories (A to Q) on x-axis. So, I stacked them starting with some helpful code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31480/how-to-stack-and-align-multiple-plots-with-same-x-but-different-y-axes) topic. Unfortunately all y-axes are scaled identically. Trying to insert different scales in each \nextgroupplot section for optimal usage of available space failed. Does anyone have an idea how to change from general scaling to individual scaling? Current code looks as followed:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group name=my plots,group size=1 by 3,xlabels at=edge bottom,xticklabels at=edge bottom,ylabels at=edge left,yticklabels at=edge left,vertical sep=0pt},footnotesize,width=16cm,xlabel=,height=5cm,xmin=-0.5,xmax=16.5,ymin=0,ymax=8,ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},xtick={0,1,...,16},xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q},tickpos=left,ytick align=outside,xtick align=outside]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,1.00)(1,1.00)(2,1.00)(3,1.00)(4,1.00)(5,1.00)(6,1.00)(7,1.00)(8,1.00)(9,1.00)(10,1.00)(11,1.00)(12,1.00)(13,1.00)(14,1.00)(15,1.00)(16,1.00)};
\addplot coordinates{(0,1.00)(1,0.88)(2,1.83)(3,1.05)(4,1.02)(5,0.99)(6,0.98)(7,0.95)(8,1.00)(9,1.15)(10,1.19)(11,2.34)(12,1.06)(13,1.00)(14,1.00)(15,1.00)(16,1.00)};
\addplot coordinates{(0,1.00)(1,0.60)(2,5.02)(3,1.26)(4,1.12)(5,0.94)(6,0.92)(7,0.75)(8,1.00)(9,1.75)(10,1.92)(11,7.50)(12,1.29)(13,1.00)(14,1.00)(15,1.00)(16,1.00)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,1.00)(1,1.00)(2,1.00)(3,1.00)(4,1.00)(5,1.00)(6,1.00)(7,1.00)(8,1.00)(9,1.00)(10,1.00)(11,1.00)(12,1.00)(13,1.00)(14,1.00)(15,1.00)(16,1.00)};
\addplot coordinates{(0,1.01)(1,0.99)(2,1.09)(3,1.00)(4,1.00)(5,1.00)(6,1.00)(7,1.00)(8,1.00)(9,1.00)(10,1.00)(11,1.00)(12,1.00)(13,1.01)(14,1.01)(15,1.76)(16,1.03)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,1.00)(1,1.00)(2,1.00)(3,1.00)(4,1.00)(5,1.00)(6,1.00)(7,1.00)(8,1.00)(9,1.00)(10,1.00)(11,1.00)(12,1.00)(13,1.00)(14,1.00)(15,1.00)(16,1.00)};
\addplot coordinates{(0,0.98)(1,0.99)(2,1.06)(3,0.99)(4,1.00)(5,0.98)(6,0.98)(7,0.93)(8,1.00)(9,0.98)(10,0.98)(11,1.08)(12,1.00)(13,0.99)(14,0.98)(15,1.74)(16,1.02)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDkTX.jpg). For making source code better readable some lines have been removed, image shows some more. In the middle and lower section it can be seen that the plot does not use all available space, but should do so.

I hope I did things correct, since this it my firt post on stack overflow. Thank you very much for your help. Thilo

Comment: What do you mean it fails? `\nextgroupplot[ymax=3] ...` works for me using `pdflatex`. You can also change `ytick` in this way.